# when memory is aligned to cache line, do we need memory barrier any more?

Tags: linux, kernel, memory-barriers

the variables defined as follows:

```
int mem[2] __cacheline_aligned;
```

two process r/w mem[0] and mem[1], and access order is very important. here do we need memory barrier to prevent memory reorder?

As I known, if the memory is on the same cache bank, no concurrent access happen. so don't need memory barrier.

Comment: Cacheline alignment has nothing to do with memory re-ordering. *"if the memory is on the same cache bank, no concurrent access happen"* - this I simply not true. You're conflating two different topics.

Comment: Look at example 2.3 on http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~410-f10/doc/Intel_Reordering_318147.pdf .  Even if _x and _y are on the came cache line, the processors can still hoist the loads above the stores.